# How to terminate a std::string in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to remove all punctuation characters from a std::string in C++. My current code:

```
string str_in;
string::size_type i, j;

cout << "please input string with punctuation character..." << endl;
cin >> str_in;

for (i = 0, j = 0; i != str_in.size(); ++i)
    if (!ispunct(str_in[i]))
         str_in[j++] = str_in[i];

str_in[j] = '\0';

cout << str_in << endl;
```

Is `str_in[j] = '\0';` wrong?

Comment: I agree that `str_in[j] = '\0'` is wrong since that's not an appropriate way to terminate a `std::string`.  What is the question?

Comment: How to terminate a std::string in　ｃ＋＋

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd rephrase the question. Unlike C-style strings, `std::string`s are not defined to use a terminator. I think you're trying to delete all punctuation marks from a `std::string`, so `"foo.bar+baz"` becomes `"foobarbaz"`. If so, that has nothing to do with termination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to truncate `str_in` to the first `j` characters, you can say `str_in.resize(j)`.

If you want to use the standard library you could apply the `erase-remove` idiom like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str_in;
    std::getline(std::cin, str_in);

    // Here is where the magic happens...
    str_in.erase(std::remove_if(str_in.begin(), str_in.end(), ::ispunct), str_in.end());

    std::cout << str_in << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The erase/remove_if idiom is, of course, the only reasonable way of solving this problem in C++.  But passing `::ispunct` as the predicate results in undefined behavior, since you cannot safely call `::ispunct` with a `char`.  (The input to `::ispunct` must in the range `[0, UCHAR_MAX]` or be `EOF`.)

Answer (score 1):

the C++ string type is NOT implemented to be null terminated (although a `c_str()` call *will* give you a null terminated string.)

So yes, `str_in[j] = '\0'` is wrong for at least two reasons:

1. The `str_in.length()` will not reflect the size of the string you expect with the punctuation removed.
2. The null charatcter is an extra charter which will be sent to any output stream,
   such as `cout << str_in;`

Using the `std::string` class you should probably not oveeride the same buffer, but probably use a `str_out` buffer instead which will have the right length after you copy all the wanted (i.e. excluding the punctuation character), OR you should instead adjust the length of the `str_in` instead of adding the null.

Answer (score 0):

I think `str_in[j] = '\0'` is wrong when the string has no any punctuation.

Comment: It's not an appropriate way to terminate a `std::string` anyway. `str_in.size()` would return the wrong value, for example.

Comment: @jamesdlin oh,yes. It is std::string, not the char[]. I forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the same string, create a new string (e.g. `str_out`) and append to that:

```
str_out += str_in[i];
```

Comment: I know this method, I just want to use the **same** string to achieve the function.

Comment: @iverson Then either copy to `str_in` when done, or use [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr): `str_in = str_in.substr(0, j);`

Comment: Or just say `str_in.resize(j)`